# Will sharing the same photo on flickr and facebook using my app violate facebook TOS?

Tags: facebook, policy

I was going through the facebook policy instructions at http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

and section 12 (b) was interesting.
It says that "Apps on Facebook may not integrate, link to, promote, distribute, or redirect to any app on any other competing social network"

Does it mean that if I create an app that publishes the same photo to a user's facebook wall as well as his flickr account etc my app would be violating this policy?

If yes, then almost all the Android and iPhone photography apps violate it because you can share the same photo to multiple services.

If no, then what does this statement mean?

Comment: Facebook and Flickr policy and TOS are off-topic here. You are far better off contacting either party directly.

Comment: A Facebook app and an app that integrates to Facebook via a public API are two different things, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disclaimer - I am no lawyer.  Just another Stack Overflow user.  If you want to get a legal statement about policy matters you should have your companies lawyer look at the TOS.

The key word in that statement is "on". Apps **on** Facebook.  Applications  that integrate with Facebook are not applications **on** Facebook.  They just use their API.  That's why mobile applications and websites can have multiple share options.

What this means is that applications that are viewed within Facebook can not do this.  That means -

- Applications that are accessed through - `apps.facebook.com`
- Page tab applications.

Comment: As others have said above, [questions regarding Facebook policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/stack-overflow-and-facebook-policy-matters-on-topic) are off-topic here on [so].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that answers my question.

The reason why I asked the question here was because facebook does not give an easy way to contact their technical support team for questions like these.

When I visited the support section at https://developers.facebook.com/support/ it said that I should ask these questions at stackoverflow.

Comment: Well the thing is that this is not a technical question.  It is a legal one.

Comment: I understand that. Please forgive my ignorance considering that I am new here and was mis-directed by facebook for this.
I will keep this in mind for future.

And thank you all for taking the time to educate and help me.
Really appreciate it.

Comment: happy to help!  I fully understand how difficult it is to get straight answers from them.